# whats the minimum water pressure for a shower/jet combo unit?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

specifically, this unit http://www.houzz.com/photos/12411778/AKDY-Aluminum-Shower-Panel-Tower-with-Rainfall-Shower-Head-52-Mirror-Shower-modern-shower-panels-and-columns

It says minimum is 28psi - is that realistic?

Also, how useful will it be to measure the water pressure from the garden hose spigot? I ordered a water pressure gauge that screws into the hose spigot. I'm assuming the pressure inside the house is going to be a little lower than what i get from the garden hose. But how much lower is it usually?

I'm just assuming we have enough pressure since with the garden hose set to 'full' i can shoot a stream of water 40-50 feet at least.

Edit: measured it from the hose spigot - 120 psi. So i guess the real question is how much pressure am i likely to lose when you're using the internal plumbing? And as a side note, the contractor is going to be replacing all the plumbing in the house with new.

Comment: Ask the manufacturer for the specs for that unit. This isn't standardized.

Comment: manufacturer says the minimum is 28psi, max was 70psi i think. Just wondering if 28psi would really be enough or even if i need to worry if the garden hose spigot is at 120psi.